# Eigenspace Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I understand that B lies in some eigenspace because it is an eigenvector and hence has a corresponding eigenvalue, but I don't understand the step highlighted in green.

Comment: What is $\;g\;$ ? The geometric multiplicity?

Comment: @ Timbuc Yes it is the geometric multiplicity

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that a subspace $W$ of $V$ contains a set $B\subset W$ of $n$ linearly independent vectors.  Then $\dim(W) \geq \dim(\operatorname{span}(B)) = n$.

Let $B_i$ be the set of eigenvectors in $B$ associated with $\lambda_i$.
 Note that each set $E_{\lambda_i}$ contains a set $B_i$ of $|B_i|$ linearly independent eigenvectors, so that $\dim(E_{\lambda_i}) \geq |B_i|$.  Since $B = B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_r$, we may state
$$
\sum_{i=1}^r \dim(E_{\lambda_i}) \geq \sum_{i=1}^r |B_i| = |B|
$$

Comment: I think $B = B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_k$ should be $B = B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_r$

Comment: @usainlightning yes, sorry if that was confusing